# Manifold no boundary and embedded balls

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose $M$ is a topological manifold without boundary. If $B$ and $B'$ are nicely embedded balls in $M$. Then, i've read somewhere that under certain conditions on the embedding using a bicollaring, we can always find homeomorphism $h:M\rightarrow M$ with $h(B)=B'$

What does nicely embedded balls mean? and how does one explisitly construct the homeomorphism? Is there a complete proof of this?

I guess if $M$ connected, pick points $p\in B$, $p'\in B'$. Sinse $M$ homogeneous, there exists a homeomorphism $f:M\rightarrow M'$ such that $f(p)=p'$. But I don't  know how to extend to all of $B$ and $B'$.

By above I think we need to assume $M$ is connected too

Comment: Usually, nicely embedded means that the embedding map is homeomorphic on its image. Moreover, in most cases, topological manifolds are connected unless differently specified.

Comment: @Federico Not for me. $O(n)$ is a manifold with two different components. So is $GL(n,R)$.

Comment: @Federico Your definition of 'nicely embedded' is the standard one.

Comment: Yeah, of course there exist non-connected manifolds, but, depending on the book you are reading, the author may not specify in every single statement, the manifold to consider is connected. This happens, for example, in covering theory, where, of course, non connected coverings deserve a minor role

Comment: How would you define a 'nice' embedding in topological context? As far as I know, a homeomorphism onto the image is the nicest possible map as it identifies its domain with a subobject of the target. In categorical terms, these are extremal monomorphisms, so I don't see how nicer an embedding could be.

Comment: @Federico Locally flat, bicollared, etc